# How do I call my columns after transposing?

Tags: pandas

I have a dataframe I want to transpose, after doing this I need to call the columns but they are set as index. I have tried resetting the index to no avail

```
        index                    False         True
0   Scan_Periodicity_%_Changed  0.785003    0.214997
1   Assets_Scanned_%_Changed    0.542056    0.457944
```

I want the True and False columns to be regular columns but they are part of the index and I cannot call
df['True']
Expected Output:

```
                                 False         True
0   Scan_Periodicity_%_Changed  0.785003    0.214997
1   Assets_Scanned_%_Changed    0.542056    0.457944
```

and when i call True and False I want it to be a column not an index

```
df['True']
.214997
.457944
```

Comment: can you add your expected output from the given dataframe?

Comment: added! @AnuragDabas

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what do you mean by **"I want it to be a column not an index"**

If you are looking for not having the 'index' value being displayed as a header you can do as

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> 
>>> d = {
...     'index':['Scan_Periodicity_%_Changed','Assets_Scanned_%_Changed'],
...     'False':[0.78,0.54],
...     'True':[0.21,0.45]
... }
>>> 
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(d)
>>> 
>>> df = df.set_index('index')
>>> 
>>> df.index.name = None
>>> 
>>> 
>>> df
                            False  True
Scan_Periodicity_%_Changed   0.78  0.21
Assets_Scanned_%_Changed     0.54  0.45
```

Answer (score 0):

Try via `reset_index()`,`set_index()` and `rename_axis()` method:

```
out= (df.reset_index()
    .set_index(['level_0','index'])
    .rename_axis(index=[None,None]))
```

output of `out`:

```
                                False       True
0   Scan_Periodicity_%_Changed  0.785003    0.214997
1   Assets_Scanned_%_Changed    0.542056    0.457944
```

Comment: When I call out.columns.unqiue

Comment: Then?what happenes?